# Is steam available in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, steam, software-sources

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.10 I noticed that there was no steam in the Ubuntu Software Center! Well, that's mot a problem since steam can be installed through the deb file on their website. However, just out of curiosity, I would like to know if it will be available in the software center anytime soon!

Answer (score 0):

Steam is still offered in the USC according to [this](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/steam-launcher/) in Saucy. Maybe you need to activate/add the proper repositories for the USC show it to you:

```
sudo add-apt-repository http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ steam
sudo apt-get update
```